# How to run bin file on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 64-bit, 32-bit, execute-command

I have a .bin file I want to install.
I have 14.04 64bit.
I think the bin file is 32 bit.
I already installed all the 386 libs as below:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libasound2:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libice6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libsm6:i386 liborbit2:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

I even marked in the file permissions “allow executing file as program”. Double click. It seems to think but nothing happens.

From terminal I tried with sudo: `sudo ./FILE.bin`
but also nothing happens.
If I run the same line without sudo, I get the following error: Bus error (core dumped)

What can I do to run this .bin file? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> from terminal ... nothing happens

What were you expecting?

Typically speaking if you run something from the terminal and you don't get some sort of error (segmentation fault, core dump, etc, etc) the executable did everything it was supposed to.

You could run `echo $?` in your terminal (straight after executing your binary) and that might tell you what the exit code was. `0` is "everything went well" and anything else *traditionally*  means "something else". There is no strict standard here though. An exit code of `17` could mean anything. That's up to the application.

Comment: this bin suppose to open a UI for installing the SDK of TI.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include exactly what you're doing and exactly what it's telling you. Ultimately if this is a closed project you might need support from its vendor.